# Text running through the line

Tags: tcolorbox, text-manipulation, border

I am quite not sure how to create something like this: text across a line border on latex.

[image]

Edit1:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=My title,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-3mm},
boxed title style={size=small,colback=lightblue}]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
```

Output of Edit1 code:
[image]

Comment: Welcome! There are quite a few possibilities such as `\marginpar` and/or a Ti*k*Z overlay picture. To produce this very output I recommend looking at section **6 Side by Side** of the `tcolorbox` manual. This makes it rather straightforward to produce examples of this sort.

Comment: Thanks, I have figured it somewhat. I would like to know how to remove the rectangular shape from the background and also make the background white instead of grey.

Comment: If you post a specific code that comprises a minimal compilable example it will be much easier to provide you with a specific answer.

Comment: Oh yeah. I have appended it to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! We usually communicate by posting fully compilable examples like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{lightblue}{RGB}{80,142,209}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,title=My title,coltitle=cyan,
attach boxed title to top center={yshift*=-3mm},colback=white,
colframe=cyan,
boxed title style={size=small,colback=white,colframe=white}]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My bad. I am quite new here. Apologies.
Thanks.